# `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)` behaving oddly

Tags: javascript, keycode

There is code in a library that my app is using, that is breaking for me. The library uses `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)` to determine whether a keyboard shortcut which is specified has been triggered. For whatever reason, on my machine, non-alphabetic codes are behaving oddly. So, `event.key` does not equal `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)`. Now, I have no idea why they are using `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)` instead of `event.key`, but I can't change their code, so I am instead trying to understand why my machine is generating different values here.

When I attach a `keydown` event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => console.log(event.keyCode, event.key, String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase()))
```

I get these logs:

```
219 – "[" – "û"
189 – "-" – "½"
187 – "=" – "»"
221 – "]" – "ý"
186 – ";" – "º"
```

What in the world is going on?

Comment: How is it different? How does it differ from what you expect? The example you've provided seems pretty consistent

Comment: @Konstantin: Great point, sorry for the poor initial version. Updated with further context.

Answer (score 3):

`charCodeAt` gives the UTF-16 code unit, not the key code.

Key codes are associated with [keys on a keyboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), not with characters:

> The KeyboardEvent.code property represents a physical key on the keyboard (as opposed to the character generated by pressing the key). In other words, this property returns a value that isn't altered by keyboard layout or the state of the modifier keys.

To get it you need to be dealing with an actual key:

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener('keydown', handler);

function handler(evt) {
  console.log({
    keyCode: evt.keyCode,
    code: evt.code,
    key: evt.key
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Type here"></textarea>
```

Comment: Indeed. I don't know why my initial question was so poorly articulated (too lost in my own confusion), but I just updated my question to be much more clear about my issue and my confusion.

Comment: @smargh — It's the same problem. Key codes are not character codes. Key codes relate to keys. Character codes relate to characters. They aren't the same thing. If you take a key code and treat it as a character code then you will get garbage. You just have a different keyboard layout to the designers of the library who didn't understand that what they are doing is awful.

Comment: So the short answer here is that I am screwed with respect to this library at this time?

Comment: Yes. It assumes you will have a keyboard with key codes that line up to UTF-16 in a very particular way, and you don't.